# Revive a dead phone?

Tags: unbricking, samsung-galaxy-gio

I don't have any background information, but my coworker showed up today with a nonresponsive Samsung Galaxy Gio. It will not boot. When plugged into the power charger, a half-full battery displays and just stays there.

Attempting to turn it on while holding the home button has no effect.

I swapped batteries with her (this is a company phone; we all have the same model). My phone works fine with her battery, hers does not work with my battery. Tried gently brushing off the battery contacts in her phone, no go.

Anything else to try before sending to the manufacturer?

Comment: Sounds like the power button could be bad.

Comment: @RyanConrad why would that affect the phone such that the powering-up screen is inanimate?

Comment: the battery is something that samsung shows when the phone is in the off state, but charging. I may have misread when you first posted. I thought you had said "Holding the power button has no effect". have you tried to turn on normally, by pressing only the power button?

Comment: To clarify my comment: the power button does not work, but neither does the "charging battery" vid display properly when the charger is plugged in.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the phone is stuck in a boot loop at or before the OS has a chance to load. According to XDA, to get into the recovery partition, start with this: Home button + Volume button - + On button.

If you can get into fastboot mode, you can issue a command from the PC with a usb cable. After seeing if the device is there with "fastboot devices", try "fastboot erase cache" and try to boot. If that fails, "fastboot -w" will essentially do a factory data reset. Of course, your coworker will lose all her data, but at least the phone might boot.

Answer (score 1):

Boot into safe mode and see if this does the trick. To do this press HOME + MENU and then while pressing then power up using POWER BUTTON